# Confidence Interval for 10 unit change in hazard ratio?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, cox-model, delta-method

I'm fitting a Cox model with one predictor, X. That is, $$h(t) = h_0(t) exp(X_i \beta).$$

I'm an interested in getting a confidence interval for the hazard ratio of a 10 unit change in X instead of a one unit change. I can think of two reasonable ways to come up with the confidence intervals, and I'm not sure which one is correct.

First step,
$$HR = \frac{exp( \hat{\beta}(x + 10))}{exp ( \hat{\beta}x)} = exp(10 \hat{\beta}),$$
then the approaches diverge.

1. Since $exp(10x)$ is an increasing function, I take the upper bound, U, and lower bound, L,  of the 95% confidence bounds for $\hat{\beta}$ and apply exp(10x) to them. The confidence interval would be $[e^{10*L}, e^{10*U}]$
2. We know $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta} - \beta) \rightarrow N(0, \sigma^2)$, so use the Delta method with $g(x) = e^{10x}$

Comment: I don't think you can calculate hazard ratio in the way you are doing it. If you look at the definition, the denominator should contain a term $\Delta t \to 0$, where $\Delta t$ is the interval time.

Comment: Edit: My comment is about hazard rate and not hazard ratio.